# How to test for bad routes or 404 page with Jest and RTL in react?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I want to know how to test for bad routes and 404 page with Jest and RTL. I tried to do a bit of sample testing, the test code looks like this:

```js
test('should render page not found when no match route', async () => {
        const history = createMemoryHistory()

        history.push("/bad/route")
        const { getByText } = render(<Router history={history}><App /></Router>)

        await waitFor(() => {
            expect(getByText(/page that doesn't exist./i)).toBeInTheDocument()
        })

    })
```

App.js (I'm using v6 react-router):

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import "./styles/index.css";

function App() {
    return (
        <Router>
            <Routes>
                <Route path="/" element={<MainComp />} />
                <Route path="#path2" element={<Comp2/>} />
                <Route path="#path3" element={<Comp3/>} />
                <Route path="#path4" element={<Comp4/>} />
                <Route path="*" element={<NoMatch />} />
            </Routes>
        </Router>
    );
}
```

and get this error:

```
● App › should render page not found when no match route

    TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'pathname')

      27 |
      28 |         history.push("/bad/route")
    > 29 |         const { getByText } = render(<Router history={history}><App /></Router>)     
         |                                     ^
      30 |
      31 |         await waitFor(() => {
      32 |             expect(getByText(/Oops!/i)).toBeInTheDocument()

      at Router (node_modules/react-router/lib/components.tsx:448:5)
      at renderWithHooks (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:16305:18)
      at mountIndeterminateComponent (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:20074:13)
      at beginWork (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:21587:16)
      at beginWork$1 (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:27426:14)
      at performUnitOfWork (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:26560:12)
```

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/react-router-jest-test-example-58527f?embed=1&file=%2Fsrc%2Fpage%2FNoMatch.js)

Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Comment: Can you share the code you are trying to test?

Comment: I shared it the first one is the code and second one is error

Comment: You shared the test, I meant the code you are trying to test

Comment: sorry, now I updated the question, You can look into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should MemoryRouter in the test:

```
//App.test.js
describe("App", () => {
  afterEach(() => cleanup());
  test('landing on a bad page', () => {
    const badRoute = '/some/bad/route'
  
    // use <MemoryRouter> when you want to manually control the history
    render(
      <MemoryRouter initialEntries={[badRoute]}>
        <App />
      </MemoryRouter>,
    )
  
    // verify navigation to "no match" route
    expect(screen.getByText("This page doesn't exist.")).toBeInTheDocument()
  })
});
```

There is a specific page in the RTL docs for the Router for the version that you are using: https://testing-library.com/docs/example-react-router/
I would try to mimic that. If that doesn't work, look into what is different in your implementation (and share that if you need any help).

UPDATE:
I think you should not have you're browserRouter inside your app, but instead wrap your app inside the BrowserRouter in your index.js:

```
//App.js
import NoMatch from "./page/NoMatch";
import Main from "./page/Main";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<Main />} />
      <Route path="*" element={<NoMatch />} />
    </Routes>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```
//index.js
root.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </StrictMode>
);
```

This way the test passes for me.

Alternatively, if you really want your router inside your App component. You would have to mock the module. But I think this is much easier.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! 
Actually I tried this example earlier and made a lot more changes but still error persits. I'm really stuck on this. can you make demo (codesandbox or stackblitz) for this solution if it solves?

Comment: I updated the question with demo link. Can you please checkout demo link? The error is still there... :(

Comment: Thanks, for the demo link, I took a look at it and updated the answer.

Comment: AHHHH! THANK YOU SOO MUCH @Mister_CK finally I get to pass the tests and it really works... Thank you so much for helping me and giving a quick response Thanks! ALSO, UPVOTING! *(can't upvote due to less reputation) ;)* and it is really easy to understand!